# Есть ли функции в Python для перевода числа в 10-ю систему счисления?

Tags: python, функции

Собственно, весь вопрос в заголовке. Сама функция нужна для решения задачи. Суть задачи в том, что вводят число и основания его системы счисления, и надо проверить, что число подходит под основание, т.е. каждая цифра (или лат. буква) меньше основания.

Мой алгоритм - это перевести число в десятичную, а потом с 10-й не сложно проверить, для 10-й код уже написал:

```
while a % 10 <= n and a != 0:
         a //= 10
     if a == 0:
         print('YES')
     else:
         print('NO')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартная функция `int` выбрасывает исключение `ValueError`, если нельзя переконвертировать строку в число по указанному основанию, первый и второй аргумент соответственно.

Comment: Да, но мне надо, чтобы вывело NO, а не ValueError, если число не подходит под основание и YES, если подходит.

Comment: Так ловите это исключение.

Comment: К сожалению, не умею, буду рад, если объясните, как.  
P.s. только начинаю изучать Python.

Comment: Как-то так:

    try:
       int (a, b)
    except ValueError:
       print 'NO'
    else:
       print 'YES'

Comment: @spirit, для записи кода надо отбить каждую его строчку четырьмя пробелами, а сам код - двумя переводами строки в начале и конце. Комментарии при этом режут пробельные символы в начале и конце текста, поэтому комментарий надо начинать не с кода (достаточно просто поставить точку и два перевода строки, и затем писать код). Называется всё это форматирование markdown.

Comment: Спасибо, работает!